# why width of double.infinity not showing in row's children?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am android developer and now learning flutter , in this sample code , I want to know why putting double.infinity as width for the only one child in the row makes it not showing
and same for column if I put double.infinity as height for the only one child in it
and of course if I uncomment the other child in the row , the whole row still not showing if double.inifinity for width is written for the other child

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
     child: Row(children: [
       Container(
         color: Colors.orange,
         // width: double.infinity,
         child: Text(
           'Login 1',
           style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 30,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
             ),
           ),
         ),
         // Text(
         //   'Login 2',
         //   style: TextStyle(
         //     fontSize: 30,
         //     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
         //   )
         //  ,
         // ),
       ]),
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you're passing an infinite `width` to a parent that has an *unbounded width*. You can only set infinite width to widgets that have parents with *bounded heights*. Wrap your `Container` with `Expanded` widget or give it some `constraints` instead:

```
Expanded(
  child: Container(
     color: Colors.orange,
     // width: double.infinity,
     child: Text(
       'Login 1',
       style: TextStyle(
           fontSize: 30,
           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
         ),
       ),
     ),
     Text(
       'Login 2',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
),
```

For more info check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI).